# SimpleCV 1.3 update & pygame

Tags: pygame, simplecv

I recently updated to SimpleCV 1.3. When I try to run examples I get the following:

```
objc[92210]: Class SDLTranslatorResponder is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL and /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[92210]: Class SDL_QuartzWindow is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL and /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[92210]: Class SDL_QuartzWindowDelegate is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL and /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[92210]: Class SDL_QuartzView is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL and /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

WARNING: You need the python image library to save by filehandle
WARNING: You need the python image library to save by filehandle
WARNING: You need the python image library to save by filehandle
```

Considering this is related to the pygame installations before, when I remove the old pygame folders (There are few of them) I get the error: "ImportError: No module named pygame".

How can I get rid of this? This is something I must take care of until Tomorrow night.

Answer (score 0):

ImportError means the correct folder isn't in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.